# use nodejs in web site online

Tags: node.js, client

I have a web site online, on the disk of my freebox (https://www.free.fr/assistance/52.html).
On this web site, i have a page index.html with only one buton. I would like this buton to execute this file index.js :

```
const ewelink = require('ewelink-api');

/* instantiate class */
(async () => {
  const connection = new ewelink({
    email: 'XX',
    password: 'XX',
    region: 'eu'
  });

  /* Astrolabe id : 1001091c4b */
  const status = await connection.setDevicePowerState('1001091c4b', 'toggle', 1);
  console.log(status);
})();
```

This script is functional when i call it " node index.js" in the command line, but i have an issue by execute this js file on my page : "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined".

I already saw topics on this but i don't want a localhost for my site, it's already on the web, isn't it ? Sorry i'm new, maybe it's a basic thing.

Thanks,
Thomas

Comment: require() function not support client site

Comment: yes i saw, but i don't understand how to do then ?

Comment: The easy way to do that, you should create api and call the url

Comment: i don't get it sorry, i found this : https://www.it-swarm-fr.com/fr/javascript/comment-appeler-une-api-de-service-web-rest-partir-de-javascript/824768043/
But i don't want any json, i just want to execute the command line "node index.js" using the client

Comment: You can't run index.js using client,